# Boundedness of Projections from Graph Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider $E_1, E_2$ Banach and a linear operator $A:E_1 \to E_2$ such that $\Gamma(A)$ is closed. Consider the norm $$\|(x,Ax)\|_{\Gamma(A)} = \|x\|_{E_1} + \|Ax\|_{E_2}$$ and the projection operators
$$\pi_1:\Gamma(A)\to E_1\quad \pi_2:\Gamma(A)\to E_2$$
defined by
$$\pi_1(x,Ax) = x\quad \pi_2(x,Ax)=Ax$$
I wish to show that $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are bounded operators. It makes sense that they would be but I can't figure out why exactly.

Comment: Is it sufficient to say $$\sup \frac{||\pi_1(x,Ax)||_{E_1}}{||(x,Ax)||} = \sup \frac{||x||_{E_1}}{||x||_{E_1}+ ||Ax||_{E_2}}\leq 1$$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\|\pi_1\| = \sup\frac {\|\pi_1((x,Ax))\|_{E_1}}{\|(x,Ax)\|_{\Gamma(A)}}=\sup\frac {\|x\|_{E_1}}{\|x\|_{E_1} + \|Ax\|_{E_2}}\leq 1$$
Similarly
$$\|\pi_2\| = \sup\frac {\|\pi_2((x,Ax))\|_{E_2}}{\|(x,Ax)\|_{\Gamma(A)}}=\sup\frac {\|Ax\|_{E_2}}{\|x\|_{E_1} + \|Ax\|_{E_2}}\leq 1$$